# How to fetch Male or Female from a SQL Server database table column and display the records in a repeater control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

ASP.NET, C# and SQL Server database.

I have a table `Students` with a `gender` column and photos saved in another table. 
On the page, I have a dropdown control of which I've bound to the gender value, and a button.

What I want to do is: if the user selects male or female from dropdown control and click the button, all selected photos and records should be displayed in a repeater control..

I've tried using a stored procedure with the query:

```
select A.*, B.*  
from tblStudents A 
cross apply
    (select top 1 * 
     from tbl studentImages B 
     where A.Gender = @Gender and B.ImageID = A.ImageID
```

But its showing all the records instead of showing only the selected records.

Can anybody help ?

Code behind:

```
protected void btnsearch_click(onject sender, EventArgs)
{  
      Int64 Gender = Convert.Toint64(Request.Querystring[Gender]);

       String S = ConfigurationManager.onnectionStrings["DBST"]ConnectionStrings;

       using(SqlCommand con= new SqlCommand(CS))
       {
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Data",con)
             cmd.commandType = commandType.StoredProcedure;

             con.Open();

             SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
             ada.Fill(dt);

             if(dt.Rows.Count !=0)
             {
                 rpterGender.DataSource = dt;
                 rpterGender.DataBind();
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the sql query surrounded by code tags? It's hard to read it.

Comment: Why don't you try a join? `select {A.student info... B.StudentImage} from tblStudents A join studentImages on A.StudentId = b.StudentId where A.Gender= @Gender`

Comment: Is your where statement inside or outside of the apply() function? It's missing a parentheses.  It should be outside of the apply() because you want to have the where clause on table A not B. That will filter out the records.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use join  in Query.

```
select A.*, B.*  
from tblStudents A 
join tblstudentImages B on B.ImageID = A.ImageID
where A.Gender = @Gender
```